# Checking for Joomla or wordpress sites needing updates

Tags: web-server, wordpress, joomla, security

Is there any software that I can run on either a Linux or a Windows server to check for domains that have out dated WordPress installations. I have seen a rise in hacked sites and in all cases the CMSes had not installed latest updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla! and WordPress have extensions that will notify you promptly if a new release is available for the current installation.

For Joomla! — [Akeeba Admin Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087) is highly recommended ([the free version](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087) is good but the extra security features in the [Pro version](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/16363) a more than worth it). While you on the JED you could also look at the [Site Protection section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/) to get an idea of what's there (personally though Admin Tools does everything all the others combined try to do).

For WordPress — we've used a few different solutions, the latest one we've used is the "[Mail on Update](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mail-on-update/)" plugin, of course it pays to looks that various plugins available there's new stuff every week.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) you can use [cucumber-nagios](http://auxesis.github.com/cucumber-nagios/) to describe the following behaviour and automatically alert when you don't have the latest version. This example is written for WordPress, but it should easily be possible to write a similar statement for Joomla.

```
Feature: blog.example.com
  As an administrator
  I should be able to log in
  And I should be able to check for WordPress updates

  Scenario: Log in and check for updates
    When I go to "http://blog.example.com/wp-login.php"
    And I fill in "Username" with "admin"
    And I fill in "Password" with "password"
    And I press "Log In"
    And I go to "http://blog.example.com/wp-admin/network/update-core.php"
    Then I should see "You have the latest version of WordPress"
```